# AWS Server Migration Service Hyper-V Connector Unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyper-v

I am trying to migrate servers from Hyper-V to AWS using the AWS Server Migration Service. I have followed the instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/latest/userguide/HyperV.html

The Connector server VM was created (V1) and seems to be functioning correctly. The connector is on the same network as the Hyper-V Host machine. All firewalls on the Hyper-V host have been disabled; the Hyper-V network is designated as Private on the Hyper-V Host.

In the web interface, the Connector server shows:

```
AWS Server Migration Service
--------
AWS Region: us-west-2
AWS Service Endpoints: sms.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Connector ID: x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
VM Manager Account xxxxxxxxxx
VM Manager Hostname(s) Microsoft® Hyper-V View info
VM Manager Type Microsoft® Hyper-V

General Health
--------
AWS access key ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS connectivity: [GREEN CHECK] 
Connector registered IP address is current: [GREEN CHECK]
Connector up-to-date: [GREEN CHECK] Version: 1.1.0.304
IAM user ARN: arn:aws:iam::134514015789:user/xxxxxxxxxx
Poller Service: [GREEN CHECK]
System time synchronization: [GREEN CHECK]
```

When the Connector server is initially connected to AWS SMS, the SMS Console indicates that the Connector server is Healthy. However, when any attempt is made to sync the servers, it fails. Eventually, the Connector server indicates that it's status is Unhealthy.

There does not appear to be any way to determine what errors have occurred from the AWS Console. Is there a log location that I am missing that I can begin to diagnose this issue?

I have tried reconnecting the Connector Server, and it did not help. I have performed a factory reset on the Connector Server and performed all of the configuration steps again, and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The Connector server eventually indicated the problem - there was insufficient memory on the Connector server (4096MB). I increased the memory to 5120MB and the issue was resolved.